# Parse values out of url

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying pass some js variables to a php file so that I can ultimately populate hidden fields in a gravity form.  I was able to pass the values(numbers) through the url, but they are spit out in string in the url.  How can I get them as individual number values?  Or is there better way pass them over to php?
This what the url looks like:

```
http://XXXXXXX/lead-results?data=50.00,8.80
```

This is a bit beyond my skillset right now so any advice would be welcome!
Here is my js file:

```
  let form = document.getElementById("form");
  let volume = document.getElementById("volume");
  let denied = document.getElementById("denied");
  let charges = document.getElementById("charges");
  let rate = document.querySelector(".rate");
  let recoverable = document.querySelector(".recoverable");
  let message_1 = document.querySelector(".msg1");


  function sendData(dataToSend) {
    let data = dataToSend;
    window.location.href = "lead-results?data=" + data;
  }

  form.onsubmit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let a = volume.value;
    let b = denied.value;
    let c = charges.value;
    let curDenialRate = parseFloat((b / a) * 100);
    c = parseFloat(c * 0.4);
    let d = rate;
    let f = recoverable;
    let messages = document.querySelectorAll(".msg");

    d.innerHTML = "";
    f.innerHTML = "";
    messages.forEach((message) => {
      message.innerHTML = "";
    });

    function formatNumber(num) {
      let formattedNum = num.toFixed(2);
      return formattedNum;
    }


    if (curDenialRate < 4) {
      d.append("Current Denial Rate: " + formatNumber(curDenialRate) + "%");
      f.append("Recoverable Dollars: " + formatNumber(c));
      message_1.append("good work");
    } else {
        
      sendData([formatNumber(curDenialRate),formatNumber(c)]);
      console.log(curDenialRate, c);
    }

    form.reset();

    return false;
  };
};
```

Comment: Are the numbers you want in the `data` query string param? If yes, then you can  just split it by comma, and your values will be in an array. If you just want numbers, cast the strings into numbers with a loop.

Comment: Yes they are!  How do I do that in php? It's just one long string if I echo it out.  I've tried using the explode() method but that still just gives me one string.

Comment: I am doing the following:
`if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
 $data = explode(',', $_GET['data']);
}` then by doing
`print_r($data);` I get  `Array ( [0] => 50.00 [1] => 8.80 )`

Comment: You can access them like any other array: `$data[0]` or `$data[1]`

Comment: This is perfect!  Thank you!  If you want to answer with this comment I can a check it as answered.

Comment: I am glad it worked :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values out of the URL with `$_GET` and since it is a comma-separated list, you can split the values using [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). This is what I did:

```
    if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
        $data = explode(',', $_GET['data']);
        print_r($data); //Array ( [0] => 50.00 [1] => 8.80 )
    }
```